# Ввод данных в Python (в решении задачи)

Tags: python

Не соображу как это реализовать в коде:

*"Формат входных данных
В первой строке задано целое число n - число пар строк в тесте (1 < n < 100).
В следующих 3n строках содержатся описания пар строк. Каждое описание состоит из трех последовательных строк. В первой строке каждого описания дана длина строк m_i (1 < m_i < 100), затем в следующих двух строках записаны строки  s_i, t_i длины m_i, состоящие из строчных латинских букв."*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не понимаю как организовать ввод данных по заданному выше шаблону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что-то вроде этого?

```
lis = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    b = []
    b.append(int(input()))
    b.append(input())
    b.append(input())
    lis.append(b)
print(lis)
```

После этого можно обратиться к данным через `lis[k][i]`, где k - номер пары строки, i - тип данных. При i = 0, Вы получите m_i от k-той пары; при 1 - s_i ; при 2 - t_i.

Comment: Вроде, да! Спасибо! Буду пробовать!

Answer (score 0):

Так тоже работает:

```
list_1 = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    list_1.append([int(input()), input(), input()])
```